# spring boot application {while creating beans error}

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm still a beginner in using spring boots, so my problem might be simple.
I want to call function and procedure from oracle database and document it via swagger.

I created the necessary query for the function, and i created service and controller that will get it through API.

OEE CONTROLLER :

```
package level3.reports.api.controllers;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import level3.reports.business.abstracts.OeeReportService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/oeeReports")
@CrossOrigin
public class OeeController {

    private OeeReportService oeeReportService;
    
    @Autowired
    public OeeController(OeeReportService oeeReportService) {
        this.oeeReportService=oeeReportService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("A1AfterReworkRatio")
    int A1AfterReworkRatio(@RequestParam int V_plant_config_num_id,@RequestParam Date p_start_date,@RequestParam Date p_stop_date) {
        return this.oeeReportService.A1AfterReworkRatio( V_plant_config_num_id , p_start_date,  p_stop_date);
    }
    
}
```

Service :

```
package level3.reports.business.concretes;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import level3.reports.business.abstracts.OeeReportService;
import level3.reports.dataAccess.abstracts.OeeDao;


    @Service
    public class OeeReportManager implements OeeReportService {
        
        private OeeDao oeeDao;  
        
        @Autowired
        public OeeReportManager(OeeDao oeeDao) {
            this.oeeDao=oeeDao;
        }
        
        @Override
        public int A1AfterReworkRatio(int V_plant_config_num_id,Date p_start_date,Date p_stop_date) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return  this.oeeDao.A1AfterReworkRatio(V_plant_config_num_id,p_start_date,p_stop_date);
        }
```

OEE DAO:

```
    package level3.reports.dataAccess.abstracts;


import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

public interface OeeDao extends JpaRepository<Object,Integer>  {
    
    
@Autowired
private EntityManager entitymanager;


public BigDecimal A1AfterReworkRatio(int V_plant_config_num_id,Date p_start_date,Date p_stop_date) {

    BigDecimal commentCount = (BigDecimal) entitymanager
            .createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio(:V_plant_config_num_id:p_start_date:p_stop_date) FROM DUAL"
            )
            .setParameter("V_plant_config_num_id", V_plant_config_num_id).setParameter("p_start_date", p_start_date).setParameter("p_stop_date", p_stop_date)
            .getSingleResult();
      return commentCount;


}
```

ReportsApplication :

```
   package level3.reports;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class ReportsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReportsApplication.class, args);
        
        
    }
    
     @Bean
        public Docket api() { 
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
              .select()                                  
              .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("level3.reports"))              
              .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
              .build();                                           
        }

}
```

POM.XML :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I run these codes I get the following error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'oeeController' defined in file [C:\level3reports\reports\target\classes\level3\reports\api\controllers\OeeController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oeeReportManager' defined in file [C:\level3reports\reports\target\classes\level3\reports\business\concretes\OeeReportManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oeeDao' defined in level3.reports.dataAccess.abstracts.OeeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object

Error creating bean with name 'oeeReportManager' defined in file [C:\level3reports\reports\target\classes\level3\reports\business\concretes\OeeReportManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oeeDao' defined in level3.reports.dataAccess.abstracts.OeeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object

Error creating bean with name 'oeeDao' defined in level3.reports.dataAccess.abstracts.OeeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object

  FUNCTION Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio(V_plant_config_num_id IN number, p_start_date in date, p_stop_date in date) RETURN NUMBER IS 
    v_result NUMBER;
    p_cur001 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio_Detail(V_plant_config_num_id,p_start_date,p_stop_date,p_cur001, v_result);
    
    RETURN round(v_result,4);
  END Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio;
```

Actually I have two questions .

1-)
how can i solve this error?

2-)
How can I call procedure and function directly with query without using any entity in the code I wrote in OeeDao?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in `OeeDao`, you define it as

```
public interface OeeDao extends JpaRepository<Object,Integer>
```

BUT in `JpaRepository<Object,Integer>`, `Object` is not an `Entity` class required to work.

If you want to work without an Entity then you should not use `JpaRepository`, instead create a custom repository class where you will inject the `EntityManager` which will give you access to query your database as you like.

e.g.

```
@Repository
public class OeeDao {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public int A1AfterReworkRatio(int V_plant_config_num_id,Date p_start_date,Date p_stop_date) {
        // your custom code calling entityManager here
        // e.g. to call a stored procedure
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("StoredProcedureNameHere");
        // add the required parameters etc, check online for examples
        storedProcedure.execute();
        // return the result from the execution
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the procedure and related procedure java code, can you please confirm its accuracy, thanks !

Comment: Hi! Validating the stored procedure is another question not relevant to the one you posted here. And in your edited post I still see `public interface OeeDao extends JpaRepository<Object,Integer>` that's why you still get the same kind of error: `IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object`. You should have at least changed this according to my answer and then try your own implementation of calling a stored procedure. If you have questions about the stored procedure then you should make another post.

Comment: Ah Sorry I forgot to change it.Can you investigate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68933269/failed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-string-to-required-type-java-util-d?noredirect=1#comment121825359_68933269 this link ? I make another post.

Comment: Nice, please also consider accepting the answer as correct. thanks