# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' on swagger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, swagger

I want to reach a function in the database with the spring boot api and get the value it returns.
When we enter the parameters in swagger, it gives an error in the date part.

When I call the date parameters to the function in oracle as 01-apr-2021, there is no error, but I cannot send it this way from spring.

Oracle funtion code :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MET.Z_PKG_OEE_NEW
      FUNCTION Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio(V_plant_config_num_id IN number, p_start_date in date, p_stop_date in date) RETURN NUMBER IS 
        v_result NUMBER;
        p_cur001 SYS_REFCURSOR;
      BEGIN
        Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio_Detail(V_plant_config_num_id,p_start_date,p_stop_date,p_cur001, v_result);


        
        RETURN round(v_result,4);
      END Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio;
end;
```

ooeController:

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/oeeReports")
@CrossOrigin
public class OeeController {

    private OeeReportService oeeReportService;
    
    @Autowired
    public OeeController(OeeReportService oeeReportService) {
        this.oeeReportService=oeeReportService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("A1AfterReworkRatio")
    BigDecimal A1AfterReworkRatio(@RequestParam int V_plant_config_num_id, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date p_start_date ,@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date p_stop_date) {
        return this.oeeReportService.A1AfterReworkRatio( V_plant_config_num_id , p_start_date,  p_stop_date);
    }
    
}
```

oeeservice:

```
@Service
public class OeeReportManager implements OeeReportService {
    
    private OeeDao oeeDao;  
    
    @Autowired
    public OeeReportManager(OeeDao oeeDao) {
        super();
        this.oeeDao=oeeDao;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal A1AfterReworkRatio(int V_plant_config_num_id, Date p_start_date, Date p_stop_date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.oeeDao.A1AfterReworkRatio(V_plant_config_num_id, p_start_date, p_stop_date);
    }

    

}
```

oeedao :

```
@Repository
public class OeeDao  {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entitymanager;
    

    

    public BigDecimal A1AfterReworkRatio(int V_plant_config_num_id,Date p_start_date,Date p_stop_date) {
        
            BigDecimal commentCount = (BigDecimal) entitymanager
                    .createNativeQuery(
                        "SELECT Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio(:V_plant_config_num_id:p_start_date:p_stop_date) FROM DUAL"
                    )
                    .setParameter("V_plant_config_num_id", V_plant_config_num_id).setParameter("p_start_date", p_start_date).setParameter("p_stop_date", p_stop_date)
                    .getSingleResult();
              return commentCount;
       
        }
    
    }
```

swagger :

[image]

error :

```
 {
  "timestamp": "2021-08-26T07:00:23.487+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not locate named parameter [V_plant_config_num_id], expecting one of [V_plant_config_num_id:p_start_date:p_stop_date]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [V_plant_config_num_id], expecting one of [V_plant_config_num_id:p_start_date:p_stop_date]\r\n\tat
```

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  But my thought is, the date that you are passing as '2021-03-05' is clearly not recognized as per the exception that you got. You are also using Date as a type, and Date type is not only just date but it also gives you time. So, try passing full date/time and make sure if you are only interested in Date, then you have to write separate logic to get just date in your format which is "yyyy-MM-dd" format and ignore time. You can use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: See here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters

Comment: Please post also your `Controller` code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters
you can annotate your date parameters in `OeeController` (from: [spring boot application {while creating beans error}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923365/spring-boot-application-while-creating-beans-error)) with  `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)`:

```
@GetMapping("A1AfterReworkRatio")
int A1AfterReworkRatio(@RequestParam int V_plant_config_num_id, 
    @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date p_start_date, 
    @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date p_stop_date) {
        return this.oeeReportService.A1AfterReworkRatio( V_plant_config_num_id , p_start_date,  p_stop_date);
}
```

The above article describes also other methods of achieving it if you read through it.

Comment: thank you pleft the error is fixed but i encountered another error  , new error code about v_plant_config  :  Could not locate named parameter [V_plant_config_num_id]

Comment: @Hakanözel can you post the new error? Cant see it in your comment above.

Comment: Yes I changed it

Comment: `"SELECT Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio(:V_plant_config_num_id:p_start_date:p_stop_date) FROM DUAL"` change it to: `"SELECT Z_OEE_A1AfterReworkRatio(:V_plant_config_num_id, :p_start_date, :p_stop_date) FROM DUAL"` (add the commas "," after each parameter), but please note this is a totally different question than the original one (about failing to convert string to date etc)

Comment: It work pleft , you took very good care of my problem, thank you very much !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939883/cannot-invoke-java-sql-resultset-getmetadata-because-resultset-is-null 
Can you take a look at this question when you are available?